# how to implement idf in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any tutorial or code for Tf Idf in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960333/any-tutorial-or-code-for-tf-idf-in-java)

IDF is inverse document frequency.

IDF = log(document containing the term / number of documents)

How to do it in java ?

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
static double idf(int docTermCount, int totalNumDocuments) 
{ return Math.log((double)docTermCount / (double)totalNumDocuments); }
```

(This is basically a humorous way of saying:  Tell us more about your circumstances, and maybe we can help.  What is a document?  What it its representation?

### Just Use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

> Apache Lucene(TM) is a
>   high-performance, full-featured text
>   search engine library written entirely
>   in Java. It is a technology suitable
>   for nearly any application that
>   requires full-text search, especially
>   cross-platform.

It provides [IDF here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html).

### If you don't use Lucene

OK, I can sketch a solution based on your comment below, and we'll see if it helps:

1. You'll need to identify the files to consider.  Maybe you have an explicit list, or maybe you have a pattern of filenames?
2. Once you have the files identified, you'll need to iterate over them, probably as `File` objects in java.
3. With each file, you'll need to open the file (say by using a `BufferedInputReader` wrapped around an `InputStreamReader` wrapped around the `File.getInputStream()`).
4. You'll need to know how to tokenize the file contents; perhaps just using whitespace and a `Scanner` object or similar.
5. You'll need a data structure (maybe a `Map<String,Record>`) to map terms found in the file to a `Record` containing the term counts and locations.

You might consider use of a tool that can do some or all of this for you.  I imagine that [Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960333/any-tutorial-or-code-for-tf-idf-in-java) would probably have some infrastructure to use, for instance.

Comment: sorry for my bad display of questions. 

Document is a text file containing some texts. Lets say i have a set of txt files for processing. One txt file represent a document. 

thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: hi, above you suggest lucene. I never used lucene before, what do you mean by using lucene ?

Comment: @Wai Loon II: See above.