# java - tf*idf implementation?

Tags: java, relevance, tf-idf

I am basically creating a search engine and I want to implement tf*idf to rank my xml documents based on a search query. How do I implement it? How do I start it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might help as a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960333/any-tutorial-or-code-for-tf-idf-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Surprising that the Weka library hasn't been mentioned here. Weka's [StringToWordVector class](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) implements TF-IDF.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in the past, and I used [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) to get the TD*IDF data.

It took fair amount of fiddling aound though, so if there are other solutions people know are easier, then use them.

Start by looking at [TermFreqVector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/TermFreqVector.html) and other classes in [org.apache.lucene.index](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/package-frame.html).

Answer (score 1):

[tfidf](https://github.com/wpm/tfidf) is a standalone Java package that calculates Tf-Idf.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Mahout:

https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/mr/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/vectorizer/TFIDF.java

I believe it requires a Hadoop File System, which is a bit of extra work. But it works great.